# Cant get custom adapter to work in fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

EDIT:
so apparently my question was tagged as duplicate, the thing is I spent a good chunk of time on stackoverflow looking for a solution before posting my question.my question is not "what is null pointer exception" please help

noob here,
I am learning how to use adapters to populate ListView, I am having problem with my custom adapter when I try to use it the App crashes and gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2265)
```

however when I try to use an ArrayAdatper it works just fine.
I suspect that I am passing the wrong context.

note that I using a fragment instead of an activity

the code supposed to populate a listview `myCustomListview` from a dummy string array `dummyValues`  into a Textfield `location` in the `custom_row` layout

Spendiing

```
package app.hujair.android.example.com.aou_project_nm;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;

   public class Spendings extends Fragment {

   View view;

   public Spendings() {
        }


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
   container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spendings, container, false);
       return view;
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


      ListView listView = (ListView)   view.findViewById(R.id.myCustomListview);
      String[] dummyValues = new String[]{"hello", "something"};
      listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myCustomListview);

      //CustomAdapter adapter = new   CustomAdapter(getActivity(),dummyValues);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (getActivity(),R.layout.custom_row,R.id.location, dummyValues);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


  }


  }
```

CustomAdapter

```
package app.hujair.android.example.com.aou_project_nm;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] transcation_type) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row ,transcation_type);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,  parent, false);


    String singleLocation = getItem(position);
    TextView location = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.location);
    location.setText(singleLocation);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

fragment_spending

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.hujair.android.example.com.aou_project_nm.Spendings">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total spendings goes here."
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/Spending_text"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myCustomListview"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Spending_text"
    android:divider="@null"
    ></ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
>



<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/custom_row_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/minus_circle"/>

<TextView

    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="note note note note ..."
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/location" />


<TextView
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Amount"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:id="@+id/amount"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_row_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="location"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/location" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/location"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/custom_row_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="time"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/time" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post complete logcat error trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning null from getView, you must return customView

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,  parent, false);


    String singleLocation = getItem(position);
    TextView location = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.location);
    location.setText(singleLocation);

    return customView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For the fast response, another question when i return a view obejct for the `getView ()` what happens excatly ?

Comment: i would recommend you to read the short documentation of this method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)
 here is also a some good practices when implementing a custom Adapter
http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/